# LocalBusiness Rich Snippet vs Organization Rich Snippet

Tags: seo, local-seo, rich-snippets

I need a clear explanation on the difference between the **LocalBusiness** Rich Snippet and the **Organization** Rich Snippet.

Is it ok to put both snippets in one site? When is it best to use each of these snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that LocalBusiness is a more specific type of Organization.  Especially if you look at the [Schema.org page for Organization](http://schema.org/Organization), it lists LocalBusiness as a "more specific" type of organization.  A LocalBusiness has a physical location that people visit.  A concert venue, a bowling alley, a theatre, etc.  Keep in mind there is also a [Corporation organization type](http://schema.org/Corporation).